# Creating a file that displays consecutive numbers

Tags: python

I have to create a text file that will display a consecutive number each line
consecutive_numbers("numbers.txt", 5) should display 1-5 on different lines each
for some program will not run.

```
def consecutive_numbers(filename,n):
    """
    sig : str , int -> NoneType
    """

    myfile = open(filename, "w")

    for i in range(n):
        newline = i + 1
        myfile.write(str(newline) + "\n")

    myfile.close()

#consecutive_numbers("numbers.txt", 5)
```

Comment: For me its working.

Comment: when i run the code, nothing shows up, I didn't know it worked. Why am i not seeing anything in the console

Comment: Check  `numbers.txt` named file inside the same directory where program resides.

Comment: @jfisk View my answer, to see the better code...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
def consecutive_numbers(filename,n):
    """
    sig : str , int -> NoneType
    """
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(range(1,n+1)))
```

Actually your code works for me, but to make it little more efficient and shorter.

Comment: this puts only n-1 elements into the file `range(1,n)` . put `range(1,n+1)`

Comment: @AlbinPaul Oh maan... My Bad... My Mistake..., i'll edit